# Работа всех элементов генератора CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

В уроке по JS **oninput** находится в файле HTML для каждого ползунка. Перенес все в JS, но **oninput** работает лишь для одного ползунка. Как сделать, чтобы функция вызывалась для всех ползунков сразу?

```js
rtl.oninput = function fun1() {
  var rtl = document.getElementById('rtl').value;
  var rtr = document.getElementById('rtr').value;
  var rbr = document.getElementById('rbr').value;
  var rbl = document.getElementById('rbl').value;
  var ttl = document.getElementById('ttl');
  var ttr = document.getElementById('ttr');
  var tbr = document.getElementById('tbr');
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
  var block = document.getElementById('block');

  ttl.value = rtl;
  ttr.value = rtr;
  tbr.value = rbr;
  tbl.value = rbl;
  block.style.borderRadius = rtl+'px ' +rtr+'px ' +rbr+'px ' +rbl+'px ';
}
```

```css
#block{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="block1">
      <p>Верхний левый
        <input type="range" id="rtl" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="test" >
        <input type="text" id="ttl" value="0">
      </p>

      <p>Верхний правый
        <input type="range" id="rtr" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="test">
        <input type="text" id="ttr" value="0">
      </p>

      <p>Нижний левый
        <input type="range" id="rbl" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="test">
        <input type="text" id="tbl" value="0">
      </p>

      <p>Нижний правый
        <input type="range" id="rbr" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="test">
        <input type="text" id="tbr" value="0">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="block"></div>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так хотите? Блок переместил на верх, чтоб лучше видно было.

```js
const block = document.getElementById('block');
const rtl = document.getElementById('rtl');
const rtr = document.getElementById('rtr');
const rbr = document.getElementById('rbr');
const rbl = document.getElementById('rbl');
const ttl = document.getElementById('ttl');
const ttr = document.getElementById('ttr');
const tbr = document.getElementById('tbr');
const tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');

rtl.oninput = () => {
    block.style.borderTopLeftRadius = `${rtl.value}px`;
    ttl.value = rtl.value;
}
rtr.oninput = () => {
    block.style.borderTopRightRadius = `${rtr.value}px`;
    ttr.value = rtr.value;
}
rbr.oninput = () => {
    block.style.borderBottomRightRadius = `${rbr.value}px`;
    tbr.value = rbr.value;
}
rbl.oninput = () => {
    block.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = `${rbl.value}px`;
    tbl.value = rbl.value;
}
```

```css
#block{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
  <body>
  <div id="block"></div>
    <div class="block1">
      <p>Верхний левый
        <input type="range" id="rtl" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="test" >
        <input type="text" id="ttl" value="0">
      </p>

      <p>Верхний правый
        <input type="range" id="rtr" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="test">
        <input type="text" id="ttr" value="0">
      </p>

      <p>Нижний левый
        <input type="range" id="rbl" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="test">
        <input type="text" id="tbl" value="0">
      </p>

      <p>Нижний правый
        <input type="range" id="rbr" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="test">
        <input type="text" id="tbr" value="0">
      </p>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Примерно так, спасибо. Но что значит знак доллара? Это jquery? Я к ней не переходил

Comment: Знак доллара это шаблонная строка. Про стрелочные функции вы поняли? Новый синтаксис ес6. Ничего сложного там нет.